# Execute apache-commons-exec multiple commands with semicolon

Tags: java, apache-commons-exec

I'm using apache-commons-exec to execute some commands in a Java application.

When I execute 'ls -la /home/user' it works great.

But I  need to execute something like this

```
./setEnvsOfTypeXXX.sh; ./setEnvsOfTypeYYY.sh; ls -la /home/user
```

I enter the command into the CommandLine object and it doesn't work.

It returns an empty string and -559038737 exit code.

Because the nature of the environment and the scripts (the firsts ones sets some needed environment variables); i can not put all the call into a script o
I've tried many solutions (like surround all the command with quotation marks like "'" or use the PumStreamHandlet input stream) but nothing has worked so far...

Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sh -c '. ./setEnvsOfTypeXXX.sh; . ./setEnvsOfTypeYYY.sh; ls -la /home/user'
```

As your command

Two things I'm guessing you need here.

First if you are setting enviroment variables you probably need to use . 
Second you want to run a shell and get the shell to exec the shell scripts and then run the following command, all in the same context

Comment: Did it work for you? can you update the answer if so? You can also try concatenating the commands using &&

Answer (score -1):

I tried this code

```
cmdLine = new CommandLine("/bin/bash");
cmdLine.addArgument("-c");
cmdLine.addArgument(new StringBuilder().append("'").append(command).append("'").toString());
```

And even with `command = "ls";`

There is an error

```
bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

fun fact: in windows this works ok !

```
        cmdLine = new CommandLine("cmd.exe");
        cmdLine.addArgument("/c");
        cmdLine.addArgument(new StringBuilder().append("\"").append(command).append("\"").toString());
        logger.info("Command win line: cmd.exe /c \""+command + "\"");
```

I totally out of options now !!!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow, be sure than when you answer a question, you are in fact answering it. StackOverflow works different to a forum: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -1):

I got a workarround: create a temporal sh file with the command, putting shebang on firts line and giving permissions, executing this file in one command line, get result and output, for last delete temporal file...

and it works !